# y parameter in Keras fit and evaluate functions

Tags: machine-learning, keras

The Keras documentation says that the y parameter in fit and evaluate functions can be set to None, which actually is the default. (I shorten the function definitions below to save some space.)

```
fit(self, x=None, **y=None**,  ...)

evaluate(self, x=None, **y=None**, ...)
```

And the documentation motivates the value ***None*** as following:
"y can be None (default) if feeding from framework-native tensors (e.g. TensorFlow data tensors)."

This does not really tell me that much. Could anyone explain what this really means? If it would be possible to give a short example, it would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

**ADDENDUM1:**

For instance, assume the following code piece

```
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
x = model.get_layer('flatten_1').output # layer 'flatten_1' is the last layer of the "model"
model_out = Dense(128, activation='relu',  name='model_out')(x)
model_out = Lambda(lambda  x: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=-1))(model_out)

new_model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=model_out)

anchor_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='anchor_input')
pos_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='pos_input')
neg_input = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='neg_input')

encoding_anchor   = new_model(anchor_input)
encoding_pos      = new_model(pos_input)
encoding_neg      = new_model(neg_input)

loss = Lambda(triplet_loss)([encoding_anchor, encoding_pos, encoding_neg])

siamese_network = Model(inputs  = [anchor_input, pos_input, neg_input], 
                        outputs = loss)

siamese_network.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=.00003), loss=identity_loss)
```

In this example, when I later run the fit and/or evaluate functions from Keras, how should I set the ***y*** parameter?

**ADDENDUM 2:**

And here is the triplet_loss function mentioned in the above code:

```
def triplet_loss(inputs):
    anchor, positive, negative = inputs
    positive_distance = K.square(anchor - positive)
    negative_distance = K.square(anchor - negative)
    positive_distance = K.sqrt(K.sum(positive_distance, axis=-1, keepdims=True))
    negative_distance = K.sqrt(K.sum(negative_distance, axis=-1, keepdims=True))
    loss = K.maximum(0.0, 2 + loss)
    return K.mean(loss)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a good question. Even though this is not frequently used, Keras allows to feed framework-native tensors instead of feeding via placeholders. Consider the following example:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
import tensorflow as tf

# TensorFlow native tensors
a = tf.random_uniform(shape=(32, 1,), maxval=1)
b = 2*a

# Keras model
x = Input(shape=(1,), tensor=a)
h = Dense(1)(x)
model = Model(x, h)
model.compile('sgd', 'mse', target_tensors=[b])

# Train + evaluate
model.fit(steps_per_epoch=1000)
print('MSE: {}'.format(model.evaluate(steps=10)))
```

Here, we specify the input of our model via the argument `tensor` from [keras.layers.Input](https://keras.io/layers/core/#input). In this case Keras does not define a placeholder (which you would usually be feeding through the argument `x` from [model.fit](https://keras.io/models/model#fit)). Instead, the TensorFlow tensor `a` is directly connected to `x`. Similarly, one can define the target via `target_tensors` of [model.compile](https://keras.io/models/model/#compile).

When you feed from framework-native tensors, the argument `steps_per_epoch` from model.fit should be set to the number of batches that constitute an epoch, and the argument `steps` from [model.evaluate](https://keras.io/models/model/#evaluate) is then the number of batches used for evaluating the model.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Very valuable! I think it explains it very well. But it does not make it entirely clear in my specific case. I added some more information under ADDENDUM1 above in my question. Do you think you can comment on it based on the specific example I pasted above?

Comment: You should set the *y* argument to your labels (i.e. a numpy array containing the labels), unless the labels are provided by a framework-native tensor.

Comment: I just added the triplet_loss function as well under "ADDENDUM 2" above. The output of the network is the loss value that is calculated manually in the triplet_loss function. And there is no real predefined label in this case, which makes it a bit difficult to understand. Am I able to explain my dilemma more clearly wrt my confusion on how to set the y parameter?

Comment: I don't understand why your output is this triplet_loss. What are you trying to predict, in plain words?

Comment: Triplet loss is a method used in different cases and I try to use it in a face recognition task. (You maybe know what it is already..) If we want the model to learn/recognize person A, we provide an anchor image for person A, then provide another example (called positive ex) of person A, and also provide one more example of another person B (called negative ex). And it is aimed to reduce the distance between the anchor img and the positive img while trying to increase the distance between anchor img and negative img. And the triplet loss function helps to train the model as above.

Comment: I saw some examples in Keras here and there where people implemented triplet loss but implementations I saw previously are incomplete in the sense that they do not provide how they - for instance - run the evaluate function.

Comment: I think the loss shouldn't be the output of this model. Instead, you could define a Keras custom loss function and output the anchor, positive_ex and negative_ex tensors. I think it would be worth asking another question with all these details. Bonus points if you provide reproducible code.

Comment: Thank you @rvinas. Yes, the NN architecture is not the purpose of this question. And you answered the actual question below. Thank you.