# How to use keras model.predict with placeholders input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to feed keras predict method with tf placeholders while providing real data later.

I do 
`z = model.predict(x*y, steps=1)` where x and y are tf placeholders.

Then I do `sess.run(tf.variables_initializer([z], feed_dict = {x: <x>, y: <y>}))` where `<x>` and `<y>` are numpy arrays.

But I get error: Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [1,1024,1024,3]
     [[{{node Placeholder}}]]

I don't really understand - where do I need to feed placeholders with values?

Answer (score 0):

`model.predict()` executes the actual prediction. You can't predict on placeholders, you need to feed that function real data. If you explicitly feed it `None` for input data, then *the model must have been created with existing data tensor(s)*, and it *still is what executes the actual prediction*.

Normally, when a model is created, it has placeholder tensors for the input and output. However, you have the option of giving it real tensors, instead of placeholders. See an example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51205167/2846923). In this case, and only this case, you can use fit, predict, or evaluate without feeding it data. The only reason you can do that is because *the data already exists*.

Comment: But doesn't this line in Predict documentation mean that it's possible? `Arguments: None (default) if feeding from framework-native tensors (e.g. TensorFlow data tensors).` Or should it only be tf.Variables?

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks.